# Pig Query for validation

Tags: apache-pig

I am new to PIG and am trying to transform some data as per needs . I have two input files.
First is type.txt

CusId         TypeId
100             100
101             100
102             100
103             103
104             103

Now, same typeId means that the customers are identical. Here it implies that 100, 102 and 104 are essentially the same customers.

I have another table(gender.txt) which stores CustomerId and their respective sex (M/F)

CusId    Sex
100      M
101      M
102      F
103      M
104      M

Now, this table implies that same customers 100, 102 and 104 (thru the first table) are not having same genders . So, that means either of the table contains wrong data
So, in the end I want my output combined in the form of a single text file with three columns which contains erroneous data

CustomerId    TypeId    Gender

100              1           M
102              1           F
104              1           M

Comment: join by cusid, group by cusid typeid, count the number of distinct genders per group, filter out groups with less than 2. the remainings should be the ones you are looking for.

Comment: Well, I was trying to load type.txt initially. LOAD "type.txt" AS (CusId:int, TypeId:int);  Then I try to group the file by TypeId.     grouped = GROUP data BY (TypeId). Now, after that I get the output as 1 {100,102,104)  2 {101}  3{103}  . So, I am confused how to filter and get to the output as mentioned in the question.

Comment: Hi Fred, thanks for the comments. But the tables are huge .There are around 3000 million rows. Also, I am unable to get your second comment where you have mentioned group by cusId typeid. Like what will be the output of the groupby cusId, typeId after the Join is done.

Comment: 300 million is not small but it should be possible to do it with pig. Start with a sample data set of course.

Comment: Can in anyway we optimize the below query you mentioned ? Also, one question I have, does the performance hurt if we have a lot of relations like A,B, C,D ...till I . Also, does GROUP by introduce a new reduce job

Comment: In general the number of relations does not really have an impact on the performance directly. Pig will try to optimize your query and will create m/r jobs as it sees fit. see http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.0/perf.html#GroupByConstParallelSetter for optimization (especially the parallel factor). Group by will require a reduce phase afaik, but not necessarily a separate m/r job.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that should get you going

```
A = LOAD 'type.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (CusId:chararray, TypeId:chararray);
B = LOAD 'gender.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS (CusId:chararray, Sex:chararray);
C = JOIN A BY CusId, B BY CusId;
D = FOREACH C GENERATE A::CusId AS CusId, A::TypeId AS TypeId, B::Sex AS  Sex;
E = GROUP D BY (TypeId);
F = FOREACH E {X = D.Sex; Y = DISTINCT X; GENERATE D,COUNT(Y) AS numSex;};
G = FOREACH F GENERATE FLATTEN(D), numSex;
H = FILTER G BY numSex > 1;
I = FOREACH H GENERATE CusId, TypeId, Sex;
DUMP I

(102,1,F)
(100,1,M)
(104,1,M)
```

Comment: Hi Fred, I tried using your solution. However, I see a few issue . If there are like 10 customers which are having same typeId i.e. if there are 10 duplicate customers , I see that mapreduce log only dumps out 2 or 3 rows only. Could it be a possibility that the sametypeId rows are dumped at different places ? But even then if I dump the data set , ordering by TypeId , it is missing certain rows.

Comment: Store I to some file first (not dump). What is the pattern where you are missing records? Can you give an example?

Comment: Oh Maybe I got it. I think the second file does not have all the customerIds which are there in the first file. So, after joining , it only common CustomerIds remain which are not all the customerIds that are there in the first file .

Comment: Hi Fred, I have another query (extension to this). I am unable to makeout whether this can be done with Pig or I need to use UDF here. In the first table for every TypeId, there can be multiple CustomerIds, but one of the customerId is same with TypeId which implies the original customer. The sex of that customer will be the real and correct sex . Now, I want to figure out , how many other customers which have different sex but same tyeId (i.e. are same customers) for same typeId .That is I want to figure this data out for each TypeId I have modified the type.txt to exactly depict the problem.